# delete some elements from a list

Tags: prolog

What I want to do is to delete part of a list specified in another list i.e. e.g.

```
?- deleteSome([1,4,3,3,2,2],[1,2,4],Z).
Z = [3,3,2].
```

I first defined the following. No problem there.

```
deleteOne(X, [X|Z], Z).
deleteOne(X, [V|Z], [V|Y]) :-
    X \== V,
    deleteOne(X,Z,Y).
```

Then, the following does not work as expected.

```
deleteSome([], [], _).
deleteSome([X|Xs], Y, Zs) :- 
    deleteSome(Xs, Y, [X|Zs]).
deleteSome([X|Xs], Y, Zs) :- 
    member(X,Y),
    deleteOne(X,Y,Y),
    deleteSome(Xs, Y, Zs).
```

Comment: @CapelliC: Each `deleteOne` only kills one element, not one value.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan, you're right! I'll delete my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit, I don't understand your `deleteSome` code at all. Here's what I'd do (no Prolog here, so might contain errors):

```
deleteSome(X, [], X).
deleteSome(X, [Y|Ys], Z) :-
    deleteOne(Y, X, T),
    deleteSome(T, Ys, Z).
```

I.e. If there's nothing to delete, no change. Otherwise, the result is when we delete the first of the to-deletes, and then delete the rest of them.

There is some confusion in that it seems your `deleteOne` has (Original, ToDelete, Result) parameters, but `deleteSome` has (ToDelete, Original, Result). For consistency, I'd rather rewrite it so the signatures are compatible:

```
deleteSome([], Y, Y).
deleteSome([X|Xs], Y, Z) :-
    deleteOne(X, Y, T),
    deleteSome(Xs, T, Z).
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the powerful select/3 builtin

```
deleteSome(L, D, R) :-
  select(E, L, L1),
  select(E, D, D1),
  !, deleteSome(L1, D1, R).
deleteSome(L, _, L).
```

test:

```
?- deleteSome([1,4,3,3,2,2],[1,2,4],Z).
Z = [3, 3, 2].
```